# How to create custom mobile site (theme) for magento store?

Tags: magento-1.7, mobile

I need to do a **mobile site** for the magento store. I am not permitted to use any extension. So I have to create a **custom mobile theme** .
 As I haven't much experience , I think it can be done in two ways..

1.copy the magento's default iphone theme and try to modify its layout and templates.

2.copy the current magento's theme (not for mobile) and modify its css and images.

Are these methods correct ?
Which one will be good and can be done in a minimal time ?
Is there any other methods that can I follow ?

Kindly suggest. Thank you.

Comment: 1.copy the magento's default iphone theme and try to modify its layout and templates.

Comment: it require many changes in js /css layout files for proper responsive site

Comment: Thanks @MineshPatel. But I don't want a responsive site. I want a theme specific for mobiles only. So should I work with magento's default one ? If I use this then I have also to include the custom extensions used for the present magento store ?

Comment: It depends on you how you want your site choose 2 if you want same layout as current

Comment: For custom extension you can remove for mobile site but you have to change where require